# Changing the image in an onmouseover event and setting a break / interval for each one

Tags: javascript, slider

I need to change the image on an `onmouseover` event but how to set a break / interval for every image - here is my code so far:

```html
<script>
function slide()
{
    var islide=new Array("a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg");
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<islide.length;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById("slider").src= islide[i];
    }
}
</script>

<img src="c.jpg" onmouseover="slide()" id="slider"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `window.setTimeout()` function within your slide function, instead of a for loop, which runs as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

you can specify the speed :" islide_intervall "(ms 1000 = 1sec.)

```
<script>
var islide=new Array("a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg");
var islide_i = 0;
var islide_intervall = 2000;
var islide_timeout = null;

function slide(){
    var i = islide_i;
    if(i>=islide.length || i<0){islide_i=0;}
    islide_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        var img = document.getElementById("slider");
        img.src = islide[islide_i];
        img.alt = islide[islide_i++];
        slide();
    }, islide_intervall);
}

function stop_slide(){
    if(islide_timeout){clearTimeout(islide_timeout)}
    islide_timeout = null;
}
</script>

<img src="c.jpg" id="slider" alt=""/>
<button type="button" onclick="slide()">Start</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stop_slide()">Stop</button>
```